# How to use multiple filters with AND on table in javascript

Tags: javascript

In my HTML I have a list/table of three columns A,B,C.
And I have three lists of checkbox-filters X,Y,Z.

**What I need**
If I use filter-list X, then it filters column A.
If I use filter-list X and Y, then only values should be shown that appear in A AND B.

Comment: I manage to have an OR filter but I can't figure out how to make AND filter.

Comment: You're question is too broad, what approaches have you tried?

Comment: What do you mean by it filters column A? Could you add a some example code, and your data ?

Comment: In general, I want to combine arbitrary filters on a multi-column list. Just like on Zalando. You select a price-range, a shoe-size and a color. And then only the items that match these filters appear.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not totally clear, but I will try to give some help.

Here is a way to filter the table to only display the entries where A and B match if the checkboxes X and Y are checked.

Change event listeners are attached to the checkboxes to update the table when a change is detected.

```js
const X = document.querySelector('#X');
const Y = document.querySelector('#Y');
const Z = document.querySelector('#Z');
const table = document.querySelector('#table-body');

const data = [
  { A: 1, B: 1, C: 9 },
  { A: 2, B: 2, C: 3 },
  { A: 1, B: 2, C: 5 },
  { A: 3, B: 3, C: 3 },
  { A: 7, B: 6, C: 8 },
  { A: 4, B: 5, C: 6 }
];

X.addEventListener('change', update);
Y.addEventListener('change', update);
Z.addEventListener('change', update);

function update() {
  const x = X.checked;
  const y = Y.checked;
  const z = Z.checked;
  let filtered = data;
  if (x && y) {
    filtered = data.filter(({ A, B, C }) => A === B);
  }
  drawTable(filtered);
}

function drawTable(data) {
  const rows = data.map(d => {
    return `<tr><td>${d.A}</td><td>${d.B}</td><td>${d.C}</td></tr>`;
  });
  table.innerHTML = rows.join('');
}

update();
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<label for="X">X<input type="checkbox" id="X" checked></label>
<label for="Y">Y<input type="checkbox" id="Y"></label>
<label for="Z">Z<input type="checkbox" id="Z"></label>
<br>
<br>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>A</th>
      <th>B</th>
      <th>C</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="table-body">
  </tbody>
</table>
```